# Adding div objects to a containing div

Tags: html, jquery

I'm new to the notation of creating divs in jQuery in the form of

```
let x= $('<div />, { id:"this", class:"that", html:"Hello world" });
$('body').append(x);
```

And I would like to populate a div with several previously created divs with the same process:

```
let x1= $('<div />, { id:"x1", class:"text", html:"Hello world" });
let x2= $('<div />, { id:"x3", class:"text", html:"How are you?" });
let container= $('<div />, { id:"container", html: x1 + x2});
$('body).append(container);
```

If I only put `html: x1` on `container`, I get to see it without a problem, but I don't grasp how I can elegantly add both `x1` and `x2` to said `container`.

I would also like to avoid using `container.append()`, as my intention is to actually understand if I can add the elements to `container` upon its creation.

Is there a way of doing this nicely? or is `.append()` my only hope?

Thanks!

Comment: As example -> https://jsfiddle.net/rnjcw8uk/22/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let container=$('<div id="container"/>');
$('body').append($(container).append(x1).append(x2));
```

```js
let x1=$('<div />', { id:"x1", html:"Hello"});
let x2=$('<div />', { id:"x2", html:"Hello"});

let container=$('<div id="container"/>');
$('body').append($(container).append(x1).append(x2));
```

```css
#x1{ background-color:lime; width:100px; height:100px; margin:10px;}
#x2{ background-color:blue; width:100px; height:100px; margin:10px;}
#container{ background-color:red; width:100px; height:100px; padding:35px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

or

```
let container=$('<div id="container"/>').append(x1).append(x2);
$('body').append(container);
```

```js
let x1=$('<div />', { id:"x1", html:"Hello"});
let x2=$('<div />', { id:"x2", html:"Hello"});

let container=$('<div id="container"/>').append(x1).append(x2);
$('body').append(container);
```

```css
#x1{ background-color:lime; width:100px; height:100px; margin:10px;}
#x2{ background-color:blue; width:100px; height:100px; margin:10px;}
#container{ background-color:red; width:100px; height:100px; padding:35px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

or

```
let x1='<div id="x1">Hello</div>';
let x2='<div id="x2">Hello</div>';

let container=$('<div />', { id:"container", html: x1 + x2 });
$('body').append(container);
```

The way you intended works if you do not create them as jquery objects at start, save them as string and then you can append them in container creation.

```js
let x1='<div id="x1" class:"text">Hello1</div>';
let x2='<div id="x2" class:"text">Hello2</div>';

let container=$('<div />', { id:"container", html: x1 + x2 });
$('body').append(container);
```

```css
#x1{ background-color:lime; width:100px; height:100px; margin:10px;}
#x2{ background-color:blue; width:100px; height:100px; margin:10px;}
#container{ background-color:red; width:100px; height:100px; padding:35px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```